# Powershell Get-PnPListItem truncated internal field names

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Is there another way to get the internal field names of list items that won't be truncated? I tried the code below but I can see names that are truncated.

```
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $lib 
$items[0].FieldValues | Out-String -Width 4096 
$items[0].FieldValues.Keys | Format-Table -AutoSize |  Out-String -Width 4096
```

After more research, is it possible that internal field names are truncated after 32 characters?

Comment: What values in particular are getting truncated, and what is their data type? At first glance, your attempts to avoid truncation look fine.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to give specifics without being able to grant access to the source data (which I cannot). But for example there is a field named "GlobalCategoryLead-Approval-Status" and when I run the code provided I see "GlobalCategoryLead_x002d_Approva". If it helps, 32 seems to be the cut off. If there is other information I can share about the field or the list just let me know.

Comment: Yes: what is the field's _data type_ (use `Get-Member`, for instance)? Do you see the full values with `Format-List` or `Format-Custom`?

Comment: I might be wrong about this. I just checked one with the name "TSConsultingSourcing_x002d_Statu" which shows as "TSConsultingSourcing-Status". I assumed the internal name was showing incorrectly but it appears to work when put into PowerShell. I knew internal names were different but I didn't think they would truncate. Is it possible the internal names truncate on their own when they are created? Or, is the limit for internal names 32 characters?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would seem that internal field names will truncate after 32 characters. It appears the name is invalid but using that name does work.